# Extension of isomorphisms of subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $S$ and $R'$ be disjoint rings with the property that $S$ contains a subring $S'$ such that there is an isomorphism $f'$ on $S'$ onto $R'$.
Prove that there is a ring $R$ containing $R'$ and an isomorphism $f$ of $S$ onto $R$ such that $f'=f|_{S'}$.

So there are two parts here, first we need to find a ring $R$ containing $R'$, and next we need to construct an isomorphism between $S$ and $R$.

I was first thinking about $S\cup R'$ but this may not be a ring since their operations may be different. Next I think about $S\times R'$. Although it is a ring but $S$ is not isomorphic to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is $(S \setminus S') \cup R'$. The extension of $f'$ is the identity on $S \setminus S'$.
More details available if you need them.

Comment: But the set you give may not be a ring right? as their operation may be different for $S-S‘$ and $R$

Comment: Define the operations on $R$ by pulling them from $S$ using the bijection $f$.

Comment: Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be two elements of $R$. We define the operation $+$ on $R$ where $+$ is either addition or multiplication by $r_1 + r_2 = f(f^{-1}(r_1) + f^{-1}(r_2))$.

Comment: You can find $0$ and $-r$ similarly. Then comes the drudgery of proving that $R$ is a ring extension of $R'$ and that $f$ is a homomorphism. The steps are easy; there are just a lot of them.